# BERT Pre-Training MLM + NSP

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to pre-train BERT for the tasks MLM + NSP. When I run the code below, threw me an error:

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (882) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1
1%|▊                                                                                                                                                    | 3/561 [00:02<06:13,  1.49it/s]

It looks like a truncation problem. But why? I just used libraries. If someone can enlighten me, I would be happy. Thanks for advance.

```
The code I run:

from transformers import BertTokenizer
from transformers import BertConfig, BertForPreTraining
from transformers import TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

TOKENIZER_PATH = "hukuk_tokenizer"
MAX_LEN = 512
BLOCK_SIZE = 128
DATA_PATH = "data/toy_sentences_v3.removed_long_sent.txt"
OUTPUT_DIR = "/home/osahin/bert_yoktez/results/"
config = BertConfig()

if TOKENIZER_PATH == "hukuk_tokenizer":

        config.update({"vocab_size":30000})


print("config: ",config)

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(TOKENIZER_PATH)
tokenizer.model_max_length= MAX_LEN
print("Tokenizer: ",tokenizer)

model = BertForPreTraining(config)

dataset= TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path=DATA_PATH,
    block_size = BLOCK_SIZE
)

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    mlm=True,
    mlm_probability= 0.15
)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir= OUTPUT_DIR,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size= 32,
    save_steps=1000,
    save_on_each_node=True,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
)

trainer.train()
```

NOTE: For the NSP task, the input file was prepared by a sentence per line.

Answer (score 1):

The error `The size of tensor a (882) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension` most probably means that the maximal text size that the model supports is 512 tokens, but you try to pass a text with 882 tokens to it. To bypass this, you can enable truncation somewhere in your pipeline (most probably, at the moment of text tokenization, i.e. within `TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction` or immediately after its creation).

Comment: Isn't it a bit strange that it doesn't do this while creating the dataset?

Comment: It is. Please look at the source code to find the details. It seems that some truncation does happen, so it's not obvious why it fails. If you provided a minimal code+data example that reproduces the problem, it would be easier to debug. 
 https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py#L348

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the number of tokens obtained after tokenization has exceeded the max token capacity(512) of the model.

A manual tokenization step can be injected in the pipeline once the **TextDatasetForNextSentencePrediction** object has been created:

```
ending_sep_token_tensor = torch.tensor([102])

for sample in dataset.examples:
    if len(sample['input_ids'])>MAX_LEN:
        sample['input_ids'] = torch.cat((sample['input_ids'][:MAX_LEN-1], ending_sep_token_tensor), 0)
        sample['token_type_ids'] = sample['token_type_ids'][:MAX_LEN]
```